# How do I get Xcode to respect my quoted #include headers in C++?

Tags: c++, ios, xcode

I have some legacy C++ source code that I'm trying to use in an iOS Swift app in Xcode 15.

After much trial/error and many tutorials, I've been able to get a basic C++ framework module working and successfully imported and running in my Swift app.

The problem I'm having though, is that beyond my base `.cpp` and `.hpp` file, any additional `.hpp` file I try to include with `#include "other.hpp"` causes a "file not found" error, even though it's in the same folder as the other cpp/hpp files. When I compile the source in the terminal with clang++ or g++, it works fine, so there's something that Xcode doesn't like.

**Project Structure:**

```
MyAPI (project)
   MyAPI (target)
      MyApi.hpp // public membership
      Navigator.hpp // project membership
      umbrella.h // public membership
      MyApi.cpp
      Navigator.cpp
      MyApi.modulemap
```

**MyApi.modulemap**

```
framework module MyAPI {
    umbrella header "umbrella.h"

    export *
    module * { export * }
}
```

**umbrella.h**

```cpp
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

FOUNDATION_EXPORT double MyAPIVersionNumber;

FOUNDATION_EXPORT const unsigned char MyAPIVersionString[];

#import <MyAPI/MyApi.hpp>
```

**MyApi.cpp**

```cpp
#include "MyApi.hpp"

MyAPI::MyAPI(){
    this->updateRate = 15;
    this->nav = new Navigator();
}

int MyAPI::getUpdateRate() const{
    return this->updateRate;
}

int MyAPI::getNavId() const{
    return this->nav->getId();
}
```

**MyApi.hpp**

```cpp
#ifndef MyApi_hpp
#define MyApi_hpp

#include <stdio.h>
#include "Navigator.hpp"


class MyAPI {
    int updateRate;
    Navigator* nav;
    
public:
    MyAPI();
    
    int getUpdateRate() const;
    int getNavId() const;
};

#endif
```

**Navigator.hpp**

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

class Navigator {
    int id = 9;
    
public:
    Navigator();
    
    int getId() const;
};
```

**Navigator.cpp**

```cpp
#include "Navigator.hpp"

Navigator::Navigator(){
    this->id = 1;
}

int Navigator::getId() const{
    return this->id;
}
```

When I remove all references to the `Navigator` class/implementation, the project builds and runs as expected. With the code as above, it yields an error:

> MyApi.hpp:12:10: 'Navigator.hpp' file not found

I have tried setting the `Header Search Paths` and `User Header Search Paths`, at both the project and target level, to the full path of the header files, but no change. I even tried using the full absolute path in the quotes of the include directly, but that didn't work, either.

I was able to get it to build by setting `Navigator.hpp` to public and using `#include <MyApi/Navigator.hpp>`, but I don't want to expose all of my header files that way (and really don't believe I should need to).

Why can't Xcode find the headers files in their current location?

Comment: I'm not familiar with XCode/Swift.  Why is `umbrella.h` using `#import` instead of `#include`? Is it related to the `header` declaration in `MyApi.modulemap`?

Comment: I’m honestly not sure but that’s what all the examples I’ve found show.